# Is this behaviour of the Hypergeometric function $\,_3F_2$ correct and how can I tell?

Tags: plotting, numerics, special-functions

I have the following function:

```
L[n_, t_] := Abs[2/Pi*(2 n - 1)!!^2/((2 n)! (2 n - 1)^2)  *   
HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2, 1/2 - n, 1/2 - n}, {3/2 - n, 3/2 - n}, Exp[-2 I*t]]]^2
```

If I now plot this function, let's say:

```
Plot[L[n, t], {t, 0, Pi/2}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

Then, very "smooth" results are yielded until n=16. For n>16, the plot becomes really oscillatory, which seems weird to me.

I wonder whether this is a numeric problem and how to find out whether it is?
I evaluated some values with high precision and they seem to agree with the plot...
This is what I tested, for example:

```
 Lo[N[17, 200], N[0.273, 100]]=0.
```

Comment: You're observing numerical instabilities in fixed-precision arithmetic.  Take advantage of *Mathematica*'s arbitrary precision capabilities by adding the option `WorkingPrecision->20` to the `Plot`.  Raise the setting as needed to address any observed instabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apperantely the machine precision can be limiting, see the help function for  `HypergeometricPFQ`.

> Machine-precision input may be insufficient to get a correct answer:
>
> ```
> In[1]:= HypergeometricPFQ[{10, 10}, {50}, 2.]
>
> Out[1]= -12642.7 + 12642.7 I
> ```
>
> With exact input, the answer is correct:
>
> ```
> In[2]:= N[HypergeometricPFQ[{10, 10}, {50}, 2], 20]
>
> Out[2]= -1705.7573316355444417 - 356.7499860560238175 I
> ```

If we plot it with exact inputs, i.e.

```
ListPlot[Table[{t, L[17, t]}, {t, 0, π/2, π/100}]]
```

we get the right result:

[image: discrete plot]

We can also increase `WorkingPrecision` like QuantumDot suggests:

```
Plot[L[17, t], {t, 0, π/2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image: high-precision plot]

Comment: The diagnosis is essentially right.  See my comment to the OP to effect a cure to `Plot`.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to use the adaptive precision control built into `N`.  Three digits is usually enough for plotting.  Start by setting the precision of the input to `Infinity`, which converts it to the exact fraction represented by the binary floating-point number:

```
Block[{f},
  f[t_?NumericQ] := With[{tt = SetPrecision[t, Infinity]}, N[L[17, tt], 3]];
  Plot[f[t], {t, 0, Pi/2}]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's faster than a set arbitrary precision:

```
Plot[L[17, t], {t, 0, Pi/2}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 20] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]